# Regular Expression issue in Python?

Tags: python, regex, series

I have a dataframe:

```
df112 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['**MDHC1235 Variance colinear', '**HINN0165 Paris Tower [HAQ] Relay Fashion', 'RJV Rust Falcon Contrast[HAQ] R/T (HQA)', 'Hulk Premiere A764FAR Quota 2112(HQA)'], 
                    'B': ['Italian Paste', 'US-AMBAS Contact Insured Person', '**ABDH1654 John and Jack', 'Romania (HQ)']})
```

I am using the below code to get spaces between any text and (

```
df112['A'] = df112['A'].str.replace("(\S)\(", "\1 (", regex=True)
df112['A'] = df112['A'].str.replace("(\S)\[", "\1 [", regex=True)
```

I am getting output like :

```
    A                                                        B
0   **MDHC1235 Variance colinear                        Italian Paste
1   **HINN0165 Paris Tower [HAQ] Relay Fashion          US-AMBAS Contact Insured Person
2   RJV Rust Falcon Contras [HAQ] R/T (HQA)             **ABDH1654 John and Jack
3   Hulk Premiere A764FAR Quota 211 (HQA)               Romania (HQ)
```

I don't understand why 't' in word Contrast and second '2' in 2112 is gone

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use raw string literals, `r"\1 ("`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. It worked. What is the issue with it ?

Comment: `"\1"` is a char with an octal number 1. `r"\1"` is a 2-char string, ``\`` and then `1`.